# How to change EditText background color when I enter text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-selector

My `EditText` has some color, but when I enter some text it should change. Say it's grey, I started to enter and it's yellow. This `EditText` is also focused, so when this activity starts -- I already can enter the text. How I tried:

```
<style name="LoginEnterField">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector_edittext</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/general_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_inner_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_inner_horizontal_margin</item>
</style>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/yellow"/>
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/roundbox_active_style"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/roundbox_inactive_style" />
</selector>
```

I think the point is in this selector. My EditText changes color, but it always yellow. How to make it became yellow only if I enter some text? **I can't make any code changes! It's very important. I can't add or change only xml files.**

EDIT: It's impossible to do from xml only, so make code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [**`TextWatcher`**](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-textwatcher-example).

When an object of a type is attached to an Editable, its methods will be called when the text is changed.

> **`onTextChanged`** (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) -
>   This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count
>   characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had
>   length before.

```
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Your Code // call .setBackgroundColor method here


    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this use **`addTextChangedListener`**

> [addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)
>
> Adds a TextWatcher to the list of those whose methods are called whenever this editText's text changes.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (!editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    editText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Main2Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                } else {
                    editText.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Main2Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is exactly the purpose of the CharSequence and all of those integers?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do from xml only. You anyway need to make a code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TextWatcher**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

> You can add your desired code in any of the method that suits you. For further reference visit:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Use **addTextChangedListener**

```
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (!editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    editText.setBackgroundColor(Your New Color);
                } else {
                    editText.setBackgroundColor(Your Old Color);
                }
            }
```