# How to change EditText background without code changes, only xml?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a lot of EditText views, now I need to change the background color. But setting listeners to every view will produce a lot of code ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328652/how-to-change-edittext-background-color-when-i-enter-text)). Is there any way to write a selector or something like this? I tried to write simple selector, the with an active/inactive state, but it doesn't work.
This selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/LightGray" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"  android:color="@color/Blue" />
    <item android:color="@color/LightGray" />
</selector>
```

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: `state_enabled` is have to toggle to make selector work for state. Although its very unclear on which state you want selector to work . So edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit_background,.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”>

    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_normal” 
android:state_enabled=”true” android:state_window_focused=”false”/>
    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_normal” 

android:state_enabled=”false” android:state_window_focused=”false”/>
    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_press” 

android:state_enabled=”true” android:state_focused=”true”/>
    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_normal” 

android:state_enabled=”true”/>
    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_press” 

android:state_focused=”true”/>
    <item android:drawable=”@drawable/edittext_normal”/>

    </selector>
```

edittext_normal.vml

```
 <?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<layer-list xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android” >

<!– “background shadow” –>
<item>
<shape android:shape=”rectangle” >
<solid android:color=”#ffffffff” />

<stroke
android:width=”1dp”
android:color=”#e3e3e3″ />
</shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

edittext_press.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<layer-list xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android” >

<item>
<shape android:shape=”rectangle” >
<solid android:color=”@color/progress_blue” />
</shape>
</item>
<item
android:bottom=”0dp”
android:left=”0dp”
android:right=”0dp”
android:top=”0dp”>
<shape android:shape=”rectangle” >
<solid android:color=”@color/progress_blue” />
</shape>
</item>
<item
android:bottom=”2dp”
android:left=”2dp”
android:right=”2dp”
android:top=”2dp”>
<shape android:shape=”rectangle” >
<solid android:color=”@color/textwhite” />
</shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

And your Edittext

```
<EditText
android:id=”@+id/edttext”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:background=”@drawable/editbackground”
android:textSize=”15dp” />
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the `EditText` background color using xml, you have to create a drawable which defines your background. Example code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        />
```

bg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
    <item 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="your_color" 
    /> 
    <item 
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:color="your_color"
    /> 
    <item 
           android:color="your_color"
    /> 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Check and try this:**

**When you will be inputting something or edittext will have focus, text color will be red, else it will be black**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red"
        android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"  android:color="@color/Blue" />
   <item android:color="@color/LightGray" />
</selector>
```